# Error reading from xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, tags

i have the following xml:

```
<Triangle>
    <Color>
        <Red>r-0</Red>
        <Green>g-0</Green>
        <Blue>b-255</Blue>
    </Color>
    <FillColor>
        <Red>r-0</Red>
        <Green>g-0</Green>
        <Blue>b-255</Blue>
    </FillColor>
    <Position>
        <X>x-12</X>
        <Y>y-12</Y>
    </Position>
    <properties>
        <Y1>v-13.0</Y1>
        <X1>v-12.0</X1>
        <Y2>v-15.0</Y2>
        <X2>v-14.0</X2>
    </properties>
</Triangle>
```

and i want to get values from nodes for example:
the node Y1 has the element v-13.0

i used this method:

```
Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<String, Double>();
File xmlFile = new File("Data.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDoc = docBuilder.parse(xmlFile);

NodeList list = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("properties");

Node node1 = list.item(0);
Element element1 = (Element) node1;
//Y1
String s = element1.getElementsByTagName("Y1").item(0).getTextContent();
String[] temp = s.split("[-]");
m.put("Y1", Double.parseDouble(temp[1]));

//X1
s =element1.getElementsByTagName("X1").item(0).getTextContent();
temp = s.split("[-]");
m.put("X1", Double.parseDouble(temp[1]));

//Y2
s =element1.getElementsByTagName("Y2").item(0).getTextContent();
temp = s.split("[-]");
m.put("Y2", Double.parseDouble(temp[1]));

//X2
s =element1.getElementsByTagName("X2").item(0).getTextContent();
temp = s.split("[-]");
m.put("X2", Double.parseDouble(temp[1]));
```

when i used this method to get elements of the X1, Y1, X2, Y2 in properties  tag it gives me null pointer exception in the line `String s = element1.getElementsByTagName("Y1").item(0).getTextContent()` but when i used the same method to get elements of X, Y in the position tag it worked.
what is the solution?

Comment: Works fine for me. Have you doube-checked that `Y1` is present in your input XML?

Comment: Copied it exactly as above and run it, no exceptions, output of 'm' = "{X1=12.0, X2=14.0, Y1=13.0, Y2=15.0}"

I can only assume you are pointing at a dodgy xml file.

Comment: @TomMac yes i checked

Comment: @RossDrew what do you think is the problem?

Comment: The only thing I could see as a problem is if the xml file is wrong.  As I said, the above works fine for me and everyone else.

Comment: i solved it thank you @RossDrew

Comment: i solved it thank you @TomMac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have many shapes in my XML file and every shape has properties tag that's why it gives me error

Answer (score 1):

**Works fine on my computer.**

```
map : {Y1=13.0, X1=12.0, Y2=15.0, X2=14.0}
```

Is it possible that you are testing with the wrong xml file ?
Hint: try specifying the full absolute system path to your "data.xml" file. You may find out that java used a different file.

*PS: not really relevant, but it's better to use `Double.valueOf(String)` to convert the strings. The `parseDouble` method results in a primitive `double`, which requires java to perform auto-boxing. The `valueOf` on the other hand immediately creates a wrapper `Double` object (no auto-boxing necessary).*

Another thing to check: xml tags are case sensitive. According to your java code, your `<properties>` tag has to be in lower-case. Your code will not work if your xml file contains a `<Properties>` node instead.

Comment: @Mark Mamdouh and you are testing with the exact same file ? or is the content different ? (xml is case sensitive, so that could also be it) The `<properties>` tag has to be in lower-case.

Comment: i got the problem, i have <properties> tag for all shapes i have that's why it gives me error , thank you @bvdb

Answer (score 0):

i change String[] temp ;//= s.split("[-]");

to  String[] temp = s.split("[-]");

and work fine with me

Comment: indeed, that's also the thing I changed to make it running. So, in my opinion there's nothing wrong with the java code.

Comment: @Nemaky i have your code in my code it is a mistake in the post, i edited it

Comment: can you write the exception here and check the list length

Comment: i got the problem, i have <properties> tag for all shapes i have that's why it gives me error , thank you  @Nemaky